# How to rotate muliple objects around the same pivot/point in 3D?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

Here is the rotation code when initialising the model matrix:

```
_model =    translate(_position) *
                    (   rotate(_rotation.data[0], 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) * 
                        rotate(_rotation.data[1], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) * 
                        rotate(_rotation.data[2], 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) *
                    scale(_scale);
```

Basically, I have got a 3D level and I want to rotate the level and all the objects in it around the same pivot point.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done by the concatenation (i.e. multiplication) of three matrices:

1. `T`: Translate the desired pivot to the origin (0, 0, 0).
2. `R`: Apply the rotation.
3. `Tinv`: Translate back.

Because of the way OpenGL matrices are structured, the right order is `Tinv * R * T`. Premultiply your view matrix by that.

Comment: oh ok thanks, so I create three matrices and multiple them together in the way you just specified? THANKS!